Can I import the full data folder from an older PostgreSQL major version to a newer version with only the newer installed?
Assume I have an older major PostgreSQL version (f.e. 15.4) already uninstalled and only the data folder left behind. Can I import that data folder into a newer major version (f.e. 16.3) with only the newer version being installed? If so, how?

For minor versions (f.e. 16.1 -> 16.3) it is possible to simply use the same data folder. (according to the documentation here)
For major versions the "traditional method for moving data to a new major version is to dump and restore the database" (according to the same docu link). It also says that "it is recommended that you use the pg_dump and pg_dumpall programs from the newer version of PostgreSQL", but how can I call pg_dumpall on the old data folder to create a dump that I can import into the new installed version? With the -d or -l parameters? Or would the PostgreSQL server instance first have to point to the old data folder (which I assume does not always work) before I can use pg_dumpall on it?
The other recommended option is pg_upgrade, but it seems to require the old PostgreSQL executable directory (-oldbindir parameter), so I assume I cannot use that tool with only the newer major version installed.

No, you need the old code as well as the old data. I thought most (linux) systems kept the old version around for exactly this purpose

Thanks for the reply. Is this documented somewhere? Why does the documentation recommend me to use quote "the pg_dump and pg_dumpall programs from the newer version of PostgreSQL", when I can only use the tools for the version they have been released with?

No, you should use the new ones, but you need to have the old installation for them to talk to. You seem to be missing the basic idea that PostgreSQL is a client/server DB system, not a simple library system like sqlite.

That could very well be, I just started reading the documentation of PostgreSQL, I am still pretty clueless. Thanks for the explanation. So basically I need the old service running on a different port, then call pg_dumpall from the new binaries, but for the -host parameter I need to pass the old service?

That's the idea, yes. Like I said, most linux systems will set up a new version in exactly that manner if there is an old one already installed.

The data files of PostgreSQL major version are not compatible. To use your PG15 data in a version 16 server you'll need to re-install version 15, start a postgres-15 server with the old data directory and either:

Perform a logical upgrade (i.e. pg_dump) to get a dump of the old instance in a sql file, then import that file in a running PG16 instance (I suggest to use pg_dump version 16 to dump the data from 15, as per best-practice)


It is recommended that you use the pg_dump and pg_dumpall programs from the newer version of PostgreSQL, to take advantage of enhancements that might have been made in these programs. Current releases of the dump programs can read data from any server version back to 9.2.


Use pg_upgrade, which also requires having both version 15 and 16 installed

